# Unable to pass junit test for uniqueConstraintException with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have a simple `User` class that has first name, last name and email
I've marked the email like this

```
@Column(name="email",unique=true)
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;
```

I'm running the following junit test but its failing

```
@Test(expected = org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)  
public void testUniqueEmail() throws DaoException{
    User uri = new User("uri","naor","a@b.com");
    userDao.saveUser(uri);
    //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.save(uri);
    //session.flush();  
    User clone = new User("clone","wars","a@b.com");
    userDao.saveUser(clone);
    //session.save(clone);
    //session.flush();
}
```

I've tried using the `userDao` or using the session directly so I can flush
either way junit fails saying

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   **org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement**
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3587)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)

How can I make this test pass?

*EDIT
It seems that my question was not very clear
my model has a field called email which is unique, so I expect that when I insert an object that has the same email, the DB should reject it.

To test it, I made a simple test that persist an object with email `"a@b.com"` and than created another object with the same email. The problem is with JUNIT as the test fails due to `ConstraintViolationException` as expected yet the test is RED.

Comment: userDao is not throwing your expected ConstraintViolationException

Comment: if you remove the 'excepted' from the @Test and then run the test, then it fails because of ConstraintViolationException, which is the expected since im inserting two identical values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so i managed to pass the test here is the code snippet
the key is to catch this exception, clear the session and then rethrow it

```
@Test(expected = org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)  
public void testUniqueEmail() throws DaoException{
    User uri = new User("uri","naor","a@b.com");
    userDao.saveUser(uri);
    User clone = new User("clone","wars","a@b.com");
    userDao.saveUser(clone);
    try{
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    }catch(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException ex){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
        SQLException ex1= new SQLException();
        throw new ConstraintViolationException("Could not insert",ex1,"what else");
    }
}
```

hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Catching `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` would catch nothing, eventhough all tests failed because this exception had been thrown - at least that's what the IDE told at the first glance.

What helped me in my case was to catch `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` instead.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You're failing because you've told junit to expect a ConstraintViolationException and your the methods called in your test aren't throwing it.  The test itself has some problems but the above is the reason it is failing ... look at the first line of the stacktrace.

Comment: but the test is failing because of this reason, thats the point. im violating a unique constraint on purpose

Comment: No you're not.  You are telling junit to expect a ConstraintViolationException and one isn't being generated.  Therefore, the test fails.  Look up the junit doc.

Comment: if you remove the (expected = org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class) and run the test ,then it will fail throwing ConstraintViolationException.